# How to sustain a note or a phrase / chord in Jython Music

Tags: python, jython, jython-music

I'm totally new to Jython Music. I just want to ask how to sustain a note/phrase/chord in Jython Music as if we are using a pedal?

I will greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a question that's probably answered in the manual for the relevant technology.  Have you checked there?  Can you offer some detail into what you've already tried?

Comment: I tried using Mod.elongate and other Mods in Jython Music but for some reason I can't find the answer or even the word sustain from the manual/user guide and sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you are building interactive?  If so, check [Play.noteOn()](http://jythonmusic.org/play/) and [Play.noteOff()](http://jythonmusic.org/play/).

Otherwise, i.e., if you are just building a Score to play back, then simply add the amount of extra duration you want, when building the specific Notes.  (Computers need to be told exactly what to do.)